# Navigate to a new view controller for every cell in table view

Tags: swift, xcode

I am a beginner coder in swift. I am trying to create a tabbed application. For one of my tabs, I am creating a table view which has multiple rows each which have a different task (A good way to think of this is the facebook app, where each option in the more screen will take you to a separate view)

Now, my table is populated with an array:

```
let array  = ["one", "two", "three]
```

I want to ask, that everytime that I tap on one of these rows, I would like to go a new view controller. How is this possible?

What I tried was `performSegue` with an `identifier` which I give in the storyboard, but then there would be an `x` amount of segues connecting to the table view? So I don't think this is right? :/

I know the contents of the array prior to generating the table, so If I know the array value, and the row being tapped, how can I navigate to a new view controller?

**Edit:**

When performing the segue between the controllers, I am using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showView", sender: self)
}
```

This of course will only connect to the segue `showView` however, how can i add multiple view controllers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to simply compare which row is selected in `tableView` and then perform segue according to it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let segueIdentifier: String
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: //For "one"
         segueIdentifier = "showView1"
    case 1: //For "two"
         segueIdentifier = "showView2"
    default: //For "three"
         segueIdentifier = "showView3"
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: segueIdentifier, sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following function to your controller.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(NewController(), animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using Static Cells in a UITableViewController

### Summary

An alternative is to use a UITableViewController with static cells. If you know already know the menu then you can just create static cells for each item.

In the storyboard you can connect a segue from each cell to their respective view controllers.

### Example

[image: example]

Comment: This worked for me when I had a UITableViewController, but because I want a button on the controller in addition to the table (and could not find a way to do that), I put UITableView on a UIViewController.  But static cells only work with a UITableViewController, not a UITableView.  How can I get around that?